# Attempting to make a grid with flexbox and percents

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

I am currently trying to make a table using FLEX, it is supposed to have a

1. main-table *which is the parent at 100%*
2. main-table__group *which holds the keys and value*
3. group__key *is in column A and hence uses 50%*
4. group__value *is in column B and uses 50% as well*

What I expecting to happen is that the elements get next to each other like this:

```
A-B
A-B
A-B
A-B
```

Given I will then add 3 more rows of this sort, I am clueless about how what I am getting is the following:

```
A-B-A-B-A-B-A-B
```

I am using Less, so please take this into consideration when you answer, and remember in the future I will need this:

```
A-B A-B A-B A-B
A-B A-B A-B A-B
A-B A-B A-B A-B
A-B A-B A-B A-B
```

Here is the relevant code:

LESS

```
.main-table {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 300px;
  &__group {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &__key{
    height: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
  }
  &__val{
    height: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Html

```
<div class="main-table">
    <div class="main-table__group">
            <div class="main-table__key">A</div><div class="main-table__val">B</div>
            <div class="main-table__key">A</div><div class="main-table__val">B</div>
            <div class="main-table__key">A</div><div class="main-table__val">B</div>
            <div class="main-table__key">A</div><div class="main-table__val">B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is not intended (not likely) to substitute for tables. That's what CSS Tables are for.

Comment: @Paulie_D CSS Grid*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after. In order to achieve the final result, you will have to define the flex items as 12.5% width and just add the other 6 columns.

```css
.main-table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.main-table__group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main-table__key {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.main-table__val {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

/* LESS

.main - table {
  width: 100 % ;
  height: 300 px; &
  __group {
    display: flex;
    width: 100 % ;
    justify - content: flex - start;
    flex - wrap: wrap;
  } &
  __key {
    height: 30 px;
    width: 50 % ;
    background - color: green;
  } &
  __val {
    height: 30 px;
    width: 50 % ;
    background - color: red;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="main-table">
  <div class="main-table__group">
    <div class="main-table__key">A</div>
    <div class="main-table__val">B</div>
    <div class="main-table__key">A</div>
    <div class="main-table__val">B</div>
    <div class="main-table__key">A</div>
    <div class="main-table__val">B</div>
    <div class="main-table__key">A</div>
    <div class="main-table__val">B</div>
    <div class="main-table__key">A</div>
    <div class="main-table__val">B</div>
    <div class="main-table__key">A</div>
    <div class="main-table__val">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gerard Maybe you should translate your LESS to CSS for snippet to work and move your LESS outside snippet?

Comment: Im sorry gerald to bother you again, but whilest it seemed to work fine at first at it did was completely unexpected

this is what it did when I gave it proper values and columns

A-B-A-B-A-B

A-B-A-B-A-B

it somehow ignored the groups behaviour, should I add you the actual code here?

Comment: Marcos, I have adjusted the code. Do you need it in another format?